# Extracting OAuth token from Salesforce Workbench to do Rest Api calls

Tags: salesforce

I am new to Salesforce and SF workbench.

I have been given read access and login credentials to the SF workbench for one of out clients.

I know I can use SF Rest API to extract data from Salesforce object, but I guess I would need OAuth token to be able to do that.

Is there a way to extract those tokens from the workbench to do simple rest api curl commands?

Answer (score 1):

If you setup a Connected App in Salesforce (any org, including a [developer org](https://developer.salesforce.com/signup)) and enable OAuth then you can use the following curl command to create an OAuth token from a username and password:

```
curl https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token \
  -d "grant_type=password" \
  -d "client_id=YOUR_OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY" \
  -d "client_secret=YOUR_OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET" \
  -d "username=YOUR_USERNAME" \
  -d "password=YOUR_PASSWORD"
```

Comment: Hi James, I don't have a consumer key and consumer secret. All I have is a username and password for the workbench. Is there a way to do rest api calls with just the username and password?

Comment: You need to get a token to call the REST API.  You can [create a new developer org for free](https://developer.salesforce.com/signup) and then create a new connected app in that org, enable OAuth, and then use that consumer key & secret.

Answer (score 0):

From Workbench if you select *Session Information* from the *Info* menu and expand the *Connection folder* you will see a *Session Id* value this is your current session token and it can be used for Curl REST commands.

You could also use the *REST Explorer* found under the *Utilities* menu to do your simple REST API commands.